# sqlite-net-plc full text rank function

Tags: xamarin.forms, full-text-search, sqlite-net

I'm creating a xamarin.forms application, and we use sqlite-net-plc by Frank A. Krueger. It is supposed to support full text searching, which I am trying to implement.

Now, full text search seems to work. I created a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM Document d JOIN(
SELECT document_id 
FROM SearchDocument 
WHERE SearchDocument MATCH 'test*'
) AS ranktable USING(document_id)
```

which seems to work fine. However, I'd like to return the results in order of their rank, otherwise the result is useless. According to the documentation (https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html), the syntax should be:

```
SELECT * FROM Document d JOIN(
SELECT document_id, rank(matchinfo(SearchDocument)) AS rank 
FROM SearchDocument 
WHERE SearchDocument MATCH 'test*'
) AS ranktable USING(document_id) 
ORDER BY ranktable.rank
```

However, the engine doesn't seem to know the "rank" function:

```
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: SQLite.SQLiteException: no such function: rank
```

It does know the "matchinfo" function though.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: After some more searching it seems that the rank function is simply not implemented in the library. I'm confused. How can people use the fulltext search without caring about the order of the results? Is there some other way of ordering the results so that the most relevant results are at the top?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green. It's worth looking into that.